# How to get VertexDelete to work?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm using Mathematica 9 and want to delete a single vertex and all associated edges on a graph but can't seem to get the function VertexDelete function to work. My code is below. I declare a graph "newgraph" and GraphPlot works fine but when I call VertexDelete I get the following error:

> VertexDelete::graph: A graph object is expected at position 1 in VertexDelete[{0->1,0->3,0->6,0->11,0->12,0->14,0->30,0->56,0->75,0->76,0->78,0->86,0->94,0->112,0->120,0->222,0->232,0->248,0->504,0->960,1->7,1->12,1->14,1->15,1->31,1->57,1->62,1->75,1->76,1->78,1->79,1->86,1->94,1->95,1->112,1->116,1->120,1->121,1->124},79]. >>

My code is:

```
newgraph = {0 -> 1, 0 -> 3, 0 -> 6, 0 -> 11, 0 -> 12, 0 -> 14, 
  0 -> 30, 0 -> 56, 0 -> 75, 0 -> 76, 0 -> 78, 0 -> 86, 0 -> 94, 
  0 -> 112, 0 -> 120, 0 -> 222, 0 -> 232, 0 -> 248, 0 -> 504, 
  0 -> 960, 1 -> 7, 1 -> 12, 1 -> 14, 1 -> 15, 1 -> 31, 1 -> 57, 
  1 -> 62, 1 -> 75, 1 -> 76, 1 -> 78, 1 -> 79, 1 -> 86, 1 -> 94, 
  1 -> 95, 1 -> 112, 1 -> 116, 1 -> 120, 1 -> 121, 1 -> 124}

GraphPlot[newgraph, VertexLabeling -> True]

VertexDelete[newgraph, 79]
```

As far as I am aware, I am indeed passing a graph as an argument! Someone please help me!

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 6):

`VertexDelete` works on `Graph` objects, not on `List`. So build graph and delete vertex from there:

```
g = Graph[newgraph];
VertexDelete[g, 79]
```

I recommend putting vertex labels on to see it really works - like here:

```
cg = CompleteGraph[5, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
VertexDelete[cg, 2]
```

[image]